# Querying a data structure that contains various triples

Tags: python, functional-programming

I wrote code that queries a data structure that contains various triples - 3-item tuples in the form subject-predicate-object. I wrote this code based on an exercise from *[Programming the Semantic Web](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596153823.do)* textbook.

```
def query(clauses):
    bindings = None
    for clause in clauses:
        bpos = {}
        qc = []
        for pos, x in enumerate(clause):
            if x.startswith('?'):
                qc.append(None)
                bpos[x] = pos
            else:
                qc.append(x)
        rows = list(triples(tuple(qc)))
        if bindings == None:
            # 1st pass
            bindings = [{var: row[pos] for var, pos in bpos.items()}
                        for row in rows]
        else:
            # >2 pass, eliminate wrong bindings
            for binding in bindings:
                for row in rows:
                    for var, pos in bpos.items():
                        if var in binding:
                            if binding[var] != row[pos]:
                                bindings.remove(binding)
                                continue
                        else:
                            binding[var] = row[pos]
    return bindings
```

The function invocation looks like:

```
bg.query([('?person','lives','Chiapas'),
          ('?person','advocates','Zapatism')])
```

The function `triples` inside it accepts 3-tuples and returns list of 3-tuples. It can be found [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/19470/12332).

The function `query` loops over each clause, tracks variables (strings that start with '?'), replaces them with None, invokes `triples`, receives rows, tries to fit values to existing bindings.

How can I simplify this code? How can I make it more functional-style, without nested `for`-loops, `continue` keyword and so on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Your code would be helped by splitting parts of it out into functions.
2. Your `continue` statement does nothing
3. Rather then having a special case for the first time through, initialize `bindings` to `[{}]` for the same effect.

My version:

```
def clause_to_query(clause):
    return tuple(None if term.startswith('?') else term for term in clause)

def compatible_bindings(clause, triples):
     for triple in triples:
        yield { clause_term : fact_term
            for clause_term, fact_term in zip(clause, row) if clause_term.startswith('?')
        }

def merge_bindings(left, right):
    shared_keys = set(left.keys()).intersection(right.keys)

    if all(left[key] == right[key] for key in shared_keys):
        bindings = left.copy()
        bindings.update(right)
        return bindings
    else:
        return None # indicates that a binding cannot be merged


def merge_binding_lists(bindings_left, bindings_right):
    new_bindings = []
    for left, right in itertools.product(bindings_left, bindings_right):
        merged_binding = merge_bindings(left, right)
        if merged_binding is not None:
            new_bindings.append( merged_binding )

    return new_bindings


def query(clauses):
    bindings = [{}]
    for clause in clauses:
        query = clause_to_query(clause)
        new_bindings = compatible_bindings(clause, triples(query))
        bindings = merge_binding_lists(bindings, new_bindings)

    return bindings
```