# Refactoring huge if..elif in __init__ how?

Tags: python, playing-cards

I have this huge `__init__` method which I want to clean up even more after watching Clean Coders videos (content of Clean Code book by Robert Cecil Martin).

How could I get refactor the gigantic `if..elif` block in a nice, readable way? Or should I leave it as it is? Do you find it readable?

```
@total_ordering
class Range:
    """Parses a poker range (str) into tuple of Combos (or Hands)."""

    def __init__(self, range=''):
        self._pairs = set()
        self._suiteds = set()
        self._offsuits = set()

        for token, value in _RegexRangeLexer(range):
            if token == 'ALL':
                for card in itertools.combinations('AKQJT98765432', 2):
                    self._add_offsuit(card)
                    self._add_suited(card)
                for rank in 'AKQJT98765432':
                    self._add_pair(rank)

                # full range, no need to parse any more token
                break

            elif token == 'PAIR':
                self._add_pair(value)

            elif token == 'PAIR_PLUS':
                smallest = Rank(value)
                for rank in (rank.value for rank in Rank if rank >= smallest):
                    self._add_pair(rank)

            elif token == 'PAIR_MINUS':
                biggest = Rank(value)
                for rank in (rank.value for rank in Rank if rank <= biggest):
                    self._add_pair(rank)

            elif token == 'PAIR_DASH':
                first, second = Rank(value[0]), Rank(value[1])
                ranks = (rank.value for rank in Rank if first <= rank <= second)
                for rank in ranks:
                    self._add_pair(rank)

            elif token == 'BOTH':
                self._add_offsuit(value[0] + value[1])
                self._add_suited(value[0] + value[1])

            elif token == 'X_BOTH':
                for rank in (r.value for r in Rank if r < Rank(value)):
                    self._add_suited(value + rank)
                    self._add_offsuit(value + rank)

            elif token == 'OFFSUIT':
                self._add_offsuit(value[0] + value[1])

            elif token == 'SUITED':
                self._add_suited(value[0] + value[1])

            elif token == 'X_OFFSUIT':
                biggest = Rank(value)
                for rank in (rank.value for rank in Rank if rank < biggest):
                    self._add_offsuit(value + rank)

            elif token == 'X_SUITED':
                biggest = Rank(value)
                for rank in (rank.value for rank in Rank if rank < biggest):
                    self._add_suited(value + rank)

            elif token == 'BOTH_PLUS':
                smaller, bigger = Rank(value[0]), Rank(value[1])
                for rank in (rank.value for rank in Rank if smaller <= rank < bigger):
                    self._add_suited(value[1] + rank)
                    self._add_offsuit(value[1] + rank)

            elif token == 'BOTH_MINUS':
                smaller, bigger = Rank(value[0]), Rank(value[1])
                for rank in (rank.value for rank in Rank if rank <= smaller):
                    self._add_suited(value[1] + rank)
                    self._add_offsuit(value[1] + rank)

            elif token in ('X_PLUS', 'X_SUITED_PLUS', 'X_OFFSUIT_PLUS'):
                smallest = Rank(value)
                first_ranks = (rank for rank in Rank if rank >= smallest)

                for rank1 in first_ranks:
                    second_ranks = (rank for rank in Rank if rank < rank1)
                    for rank2 in second_ranks:
                        if token != 'X_OFFSUIT_PLUS':
                            self._add_suited(rank1.value + rank2.value)
                        if token != 'X_SUITED_PLUS':
                            self._add_offsuit(rank1.value + rank2.value)

            elif token in ('X_MINUS', 'X_SUITED_MINUS', 'X_OFFSUIT_MINUS'):
                biggest = Rank(value)
                first_ranks = (rank for rank in Rank if rank <= biggest)

                for rank1 in first_ranks:
                    second_ranks = (rank for rank in Rank if rank < rank1)
                    for rank2 in second_ranks:
                        if token != 'X_OFFSUIT_MINUS':
                            self._add_suited(rank1.value + rank2.value)
                        if token != 'X_SUITED_MINUS':
                            self._add_offsuit(rank1.value + rank2.value)

            elif token == 'COMBO':
                combo = Combo(value)
                if combo.is_pair:
                    self._pairs.add(combo)
                elif combo.is_suited:
                    self._suiteds.add(combo)
                else:
                    self._offsuits.add(combo)

            elif token == 'OFFSUIT_PLUS':
                smaller, bigger = Rank(value[0]), Rank(value[1])
                for rank in (rank.value for rank in Rank if smaller <= rank < bigger):
                    self._add_offsuit(value[1] + rank)

            elif token == 'OFFSUIT_MINUS':
                smaller, bigger = Rank(value[0]), Rank(value[1])
                for rank in (rank.value for rank in Rank if rank <= smaller):
                    self._add_offsuit(value[1] + rank)

            elif token == 'SUITED_PLUS':
                smaller, bigger = Rank(value[0]), Rank(value[1])
                for rank in (rank.value for rank in Rank if smaller <= rank < bigger):
                    self._add_suited(value[1] + rank)

            elif token == 'SUITED_MINUS':
                smaller, bigger = Rank(value[0]), Rank(value[1])
                for rank in (rank.value for rank in Rank if rank <= smaller):
                    self._add_suited(value[1] + rank)

            elif token == 'BOTH_DASH':
                smaller, bigger = Rank(value[1]), Rank(value[2])
                for rank in (rank.value for rank in Rank if smaller <= rank <= bigger):
                    self._add_offsuit(value[0] + rank)
                    self._add_suited(value[0] + rank)

            elif token == 'OFFSUIT_DASH':
                smaller, bigger = Rank(value[1]), Rank(value[2])
                for rank in (rank.value for rank in Rank if smaller <= rank <= bigger):
                    self._add_offsuit(value[0] + rank)

            elif token == 'SUITED_DASH':
                smaller, bigger = Rank(value[1]), Rank(value[2])
                for rank in (rank.value for rank in Rank if smaller <= rank <= bigger):
                    self._add_suited(value[0] + rank)
```

There is a similar question: [Refactor deeply nested if-else](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/19470/refactor-deeply-nested-if-else), but my conditions cannot be simplified any more (well possibly except the `token in ('X_PLUS', 'X_SUITED_PLUS', 'X_OFFSUIT_PLUS')` parts could be flatten out).

Maybe I could wrap small functions, but the `if..elif` part would still be huge. Could you show a real life example how these vast conditions are simplified usually?

Answer (score 3):

Typically massive if elifs are equivalent to a switch statement. Python doesn't have switch statements and instead relies on dicts.

I would have a dictionary of str: function, which would break up the huge method and avoid the huge if elifs.

As an aside, many of these blocks are very closely related, often only the list in the for loop is different (xxx_plus and xxx_minus). It would be nice if that could be factored out into a single method, with an arg to say how the list should be created.

Answer (score 2):

For each token you are describing a triple of sets (pairs,suited,off_suite) which are parameterized over a value.

It would be nice to have a code like this in your `__init__`:

```
    for token, value in _RegexRangeLexer(range):
        tok = tokens[token](value)
        self._add_pair(tok.pair)
        self._add_suited(tok.suited)
        self._add_off_suite(tok.off_suite)
```

which can be achieved if you define a dictionary of classes. The code could become even longer, but separates more clearly the logic of your Range class by the information about different Tokens. If these Tokens have other functionality using a class becomes even more convenient.

The definition of token is clearly separated and does not interfere in the logic of the application. Also, adding a new token is a matter of defining a new class and registering it in the dictionary of tokens. Similar token could benefit in inheritance. For example:

```
class TokenX(object):
    kind = None # define in derived classes    

    def __init__(self,value):
        setattr(self,self.kind,value)

class TokenXOffSuit(TokenX):
    kind = 'off_suit'

class TokenXSuited(TokenX):
    kind = 'suited'
```

Comment: Wow, I did not even thought about separating the token definitions! I already separated the lexer, because at the first time I was doing parsing also, so even the parser logic was in the `__init__` :) but this should clear things out even more! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The usual answer to this is dynamic methods:

```
def __init__(self, range=''):
    ...
    for token, value in _RegexRangeLexer(range):
        try:
            fun = getattr(self, 'token_' + token.lower())
        except AttributeError:
            # no such token! do something...

        fun(value)
```

Basically, this generates a method name from the token and attempts to call it. Then, define handler methods like:

```
def token_all(self, value):
    for card in itertools.combinations('AKQJT98765432', 2):
        self._add_offsuit(card)
        self._add_suited(card)
    for rank in 'AKQJT98765432':
        self._add_pair(rank)

def token_pair(self, value):
    # etc
    pass
```

This keeps your main loop tidy and allows you to add new token types easily.

As a side note, `range` is a poor choice for a variable name because it masks the builtin with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

For each token, define a function which takes a `Range` instance and a value.

Then, define a dictionary which maps each token to the corresponding function.

Finally, iterate the tokens and invoke each of the functions through the dictionary.

```
class Range:

    def ALL(range,value):
        for card in itertools.combinations('AKQJT98765432', 2):
            range._add_offsuit(card)
            range._add_suited(card)
        for rank in 'AKQJT98765432':
            range._add_pair(rank)

    def PAIR(range,value):
        range._add_pair(value)

    def PAIR_PLUS(range,value):
        smallest = Rank(value)
        for rank in (rank.value for rank in Rank if rank >= smallest):
            range._add_pair(rank)

    def PAIR_MINUS(range,value):
        biggest = Rank(value)
        for rank in (rank.value for rank in Rank if rank <= biggest):
            range._add_pair(rank)

    def PAIR_DASH(range,value):
        first, second = Rank(value[0]), Rank(value[1])
        ranks = (rank.value for rank in Rank if first <= rank <= second)
        for rank in ranks:
            range._add_pair(rank)

    def BOTH(range,value):
        range._add_offsuit(value[0] + value[1])
        range._add_suited(value[0] + value[1])

    def X_BOTH(range,value):
        for rank in (r.value for r in Rank if r < Rank(value)):
            range._add_suited(value + rank)
            range._add_offsuit(value + rank)

    def OFFSUIT(range,value):
        range._add_offsuit(value[0] + value[1])

    def SUITED(range,value):
        range._add_suited(value[0] + value[1])

    def X_OFFSUIT(range,value):
        biggest = Rank(value)
        for rank in (rank.value for rank in Rank if rank < biggest):
            range._add_offsuit(value + rank)

    def X_SUITED(range,value):
        biggest = Rank(value)
        for rank in (rank.value for rank in Rank if rank < biggest):
            range._add_suited(value + rank)

    def BOTH_PLUS(range,value):
        smaller, bigger = Rank(value[0]), Rank(value[1])
        for rank in (rank.value for rank in Rank if smaller <= rank < bigger):
            range._add_suited(value[1] + rank)
            range._add_offsuit(value[1] + rank)

    def BOTH_MINUS(range,value):
        smaller, bigger = Rank(value[0]), Rank(value[1])
        for rank in (rank.value for rank in Rank if rank <= smaller):
            range._add_suited(value[1] + rank)
            range._add_offsuit(value[1] + rank)

    def X_PLUS(range,value):
        smallest = Rank(value)
        first_ranks = (rank for rank in Rank if rank >= smallest)
        for rank1 in first_ranks:
            second_ranks = (rank for rank in Rank if rank < rank1)
            for rank2 in second_ranks:
                range._add_suited(rank1.value + rank2.value)
                range._add_offsuit(rank1.value + rank2.value)

    def X_SUITED_PLUS(range,value):
        smallest = Rank(value)
        first_ranks = (rank for rank in Rank if rank >= smallest)
        for rank1 in first_ranks:
            second_ranks = (rank for rank in Rank if rank < rank1)
            for rank2 in second_ranks:
                range._add_suited(rank1.value + rank2.value)

    def X_OFFSUIT_PLUS(range,value):
        smallest = Rank(value)
        first_ranks = (rank for rank in Rank if rank >= smallest)
        for rank1 in first_ranks:
            second_ranks = (rank for rank in Rank if rank < rank1)
            for rank2 in second_ranks:
                range._add_offsuit(rank1.value + rank2.value)

    def X_MINUS(range,value):
        biggest = Rank(value)
        first_ranks = (rank for rank in Rank if rank <= biggest)
        for rank1 in first_ranks:
            second_ranks = (rank for rank in Rank if rank < rank1)
            for rank2 in second_ranks:
                range._add_suited(rank1.value + rank2.value)
                range._add_offsuit(rank1.value + rank2.value)

    def X_SUITED_MINUS(range,value):
        biggest = Rank(value)
        first_ranks = (rank for rank in Rank if rank <= biggest)
        for rank1 in first_ranks:
            second_ranks = (rank for rank in Rank if rank < rank1)
            for rank2 in second_ranks:
                range._add_suited(rank1.value + rank2.value)

    def X_OFFSUIT_MINUS(range,value):
        biggest = Rank(value)
        first_ranks = (rank for rank in Rank if rank <= biggest)
        for rank1 in first_ranks:
            second_ranks = (rank for rank in Rank if rank < rank1)
            for rank2 in second_ranks:
                range._add_offsuit(rank1.value + rank2.value)

    def COMBO(range,value):
        combo = Combo(value)
        if combo.is_pair:
            range._pairs.add(combo)
        elif combo.is_suited:
            range._suiteds.add(combo)
        else:
            range._offsuits.add(combo)

    def OFFSUIT_PLUS(range,value):
        smaller, bigger = Rank(value[0]), Rank(value[1])
        for rank in (rank.value for rank in Rank if smaller <= rank < bigger):
            range._add_offsuit(value[1] + rank)

    def OFFSUIT_MINUS(range,value):
        smaller, bigger = Rank(value[0]), Rank(value[1])
        for rank in (rank.value for rank in Rank if rank <= smaller):
            range._add_offsuit(value[1] + rank)

    def SUITED_PLUS(range,value):
        smaller, bigger = Rank(value[0]), Rank(value[1])
        for rank in (rank.value for rank in Rank if smaller <= rank < bigger):
            range._add_suited(value[1] + rank)

    def SUITED_MINUS(range,value):
        smaller, bigger = Rank(value[0]), Rank(value[1])
        for rank in (rank.value for rank in Rank if rank <= smaller):
            range._add_suited(value[1] + rank)

    def BOTH_DASH(range,value):
        smaller, bigger = Rank(value[1]), Rank(value[2])
        for rank in (rank.value for rank in Rank if smaller <= rank <= bigger):
            range._add_offsuit(value[0] + rank)
            range._add_suited(value[0] + rank)

    def OFFSUIT_DASH(range,value):
        smaller, bigger = Rank(value[1]), Rank(value[2])
        for rank in (rank.value for rank in Rank if smaller <= rank <= bigger):
            range._add_offsuit(value[0] + rank)

    def SUITED_DASH(range,value):
        smaller, bigger = Rank(value[1]), Rank(value[2])
        for rank in (rank.value for rank in Rank if smaller <= rank <= bigger):
            range._add_suited(value[0] + rank)

    func_dict = {
        'ALL'             : ALL            ,
        'PAIR'            : PAIR           ,
        'PAIR_PLUS'       : PAIR_PLUS      ,
        'PAIR_MINUS'      : PAIR_MINUS     ,
        'PAIR_DASH'       : PAIR_DASH      ,
        'BOTH'            : BOTH           ,
        'X_BOTH'          : X_BOTH         ,
        'OFFSUIT'         : OFFSUIT        ,
        'SUITED'          : SUITED         ,
        'X_OFFSUIT'       : X_OFFSUIT      ,
        'X_SUITED'        : X_SUITED       ,
        'BOTH_PLUS'       : BOTH_PLUS      ,
        'BOTH_MINUS'      : BOTH_MINUS     ,
        'X_PLUS'          : X_PLUS         ,
        'X_SUITED_PLUS'   : X_SUITED_PLUS  ,
        'X_OFFSUIT_PLUS'  : X_OFFSUIT_PLUS ,
        'X_MINUS'         : X_MINUS        ,
        'X_SUITED_MINUS'  : X_SUITED_MINUS ,
        'X_OFFSUIT_MINUS' : X_OFFSUIT_MINUS,
        'COMBO'           : COMBO          ,
        'OFFSUIT_PLUS'    : OFFSUIT_PLUS   ,
        'OFFSUIT_MINUS'   : OFFSUIT_MINUS  ,
        'SUITED_PLUS'     : SUITED_PLUS    ,
        'SUITED_MINUS'    : SUITED_MINUS   ,
        'BOTH_DASH'       : BOTH_DASH      ,
        'OFFSUIT_DASH'    : OFFSUIT_DASH   ,
        'SUITED_DASH'     : SUITED_DASH    ,
    }        

    def __init__(self,range=''):
        self._pairs = set()
        self._suiteds = set()
        self._offsuits = set()
        for token, value in _RegexRangeLexer(range):
            if token in Range.func_dict:
                Range.func_dict[token](self,value)
```

Comment: This is not DRY. Also it's better to define those functions as methods on the Range class instead for obvious reasons.

Comment: @Walkman: I **have** defined them in the `Range` class, but as class-methods rather than instance-methods (i.e., they don't have a `self`).